# What are the polite limits of editing others' posts for formatting?

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

Related: [How should I approach editing?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/how-should-i-approach-editing)

RPG.se seems to lend itself to longer answers than some other sites.  Because of this, formatting becomes even more important.

Before I commit to reading a wall of text, I like to know there is something worthwhile in it (and I read a lot of answers on this site). Typically, **I try to skim each answer for main ideas before reading**.  This becomes significantly easier if there is any bold or italics.

Occasionally, I see an answer that has a lot of interesting information, but is difficult to scan.  Some especially long questions are difficult to digest, even on a read-through.

On occasion, **I edit posts in order to bold key points**. I have even added a paragraph break or two.  However, I am wary of offending someone (especially because I only edit answers that I think have excellent content!).

What are the limits of politeness?  **Are these formatting edits disrespectful of the author's intent?**

Examples:

- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/9619/revisions
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/9658/revisions

Comment: I appreciate it when people improve my answers.

Answer (score 16):

In general you are encouraged to edit for formatting, as long as it is significant.  If you're going to bold *one word* or add *a period* it's probably not worth the edit.  Also, please do not edit large swaths of questions/answers at a time, as this floods the front page with whatever you're reading and hides current questions.

**In short please made substantive improvements, but don't get carried away.**

Comment: Yeah. Everything in moderation and good time. :)

Comment: Although this *might* not be helpful, my suggestion is to ***go nuts***. Seriously if it helps, it helps. Leave a comment "Oh Hai I fixd that for you!!" will do. Even mention they are free to roll it back. If they don't like it, at worst they'll roll back at best it'll encourage them to edit it *themselves*.